# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes in plugin Accordion on WordPress

Tags: plugins

Use the Accordion plugin of Wordpress. But after changing the name of the site (URL of my site), I have errors including the script add-acc.php.

The error message is:

> Notice: unserialize (): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes.

The line concerned in the file is:

```
$ accordion_data = unserialize (get_post_meta ($ post-> ID, 'wpsm_accordion_data', true));
```

I can not solve this problem. As a result, the publications do not appear anymore.

Can someone help me?

thank you in advance

Comment: How have you updated the URL of your site? Using a plugin like "Better Search & Replace" or through a database search/replace?

Comment: Is it really `$ post-> ID`? It should be `$post-> ID`. (without blank) I think it's not, because you also write `$ accordion_data`.

Comment: This code is without blank. PHP don't accept blank in variable name. $accordion_data = unserialize (get_post_meta ($ post->ID, 'wpsm_accordion_data', true));